# Using an IF ELSE statement inside a FOR loop in UNIX

Tags: unix, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to use an IF/ELSE statement inside a FOR loops to generate two output files:
count1 with numbers 1-5;
count2 with numbers 6-10

I am trying

```
for i in {1..10}
do
        if [ $i -le 5 ]
        then
                echo $i > count1.out
        else
                echo $i > count2.out
        fi
done
```

but count1 only has "5" in it and count2 shows "10"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>`. `>>` appends text, but `>` overwrites whatever is in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the truncate-redirect operator, `>`.

You likely intended to use the append-redirect operator, `>>`.

[Consider reading up on BASh I/O redirection in general.](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) It will help you a lot with understanding shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Using `>` to redirect to a file replaces the whole content of the file.
What you actually want to do is append to the file, which you can do with `>>` like so:

```
echo "hello " > somefile.out # replace the contents of whatever is in somefile.out
echo "world!" >> somefile.out # append more stuff to somefile.out
```

More info here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html